# Annotation SOURCE Retention Policy

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

From the Java doc:

CLASS:
    Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.

RUNTIME:
    Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively.

SOURCE:
    Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

I understand the usages of RUNTIME (in order to use annotation with reflection) and CLASS (for the compiler) but I don't understand when it can be usefull to use

> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)

Can you explain?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Things like @SuppressWarnings, @Override are annotations used by the compiler - not needed at runtime.  For those RetentionPolicy.SOURCE would make sense.  Also annotations can be used to generate code (look at Spring ROO) - such annotation are also not required at run time.

Comment: and why not RetentionPolicy.CLASS?

Comment: +1: Some annotations used by the compiler are CLASS retention.

Comment: Those are not needed in the ByteCode (in the .class file).

Comment: @JohnJohnGa, The compiler only needs the SuppressWarnings and Override annotations for the code it is immediately compiling.  Deprecated needs to be CLASS or RUNTIME as it can result in a warning in code compiled later (which uses it)

Comment: I sometime create `SOURCE` annotation(s) as "To dos", "gotchas", "pitfalls" or simply "reminders". I can choose to write processors for it or search it in IDE

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes perfect sense - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43910948/3009968.

You would not like to include a dependency, the desired effects of which are realized even before the code is compiled. E.g. @SuppressWarnings

You would not like to include a dependency which is used by compiler to let's say generate code but not at all required during runtime. E.g. as mentioned already in previous answer -[spring roo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/tree/master/annotations).

Answer (score -1):

**RetentionPolicy.CLASS** -  The defined annotation will be stored in the *.class* file, but not available at runtime. This is the default retention policy if you do not specify any retention policy at all.

**RetentionPolicy.SOURCE** - The defined annotation will be ignored by the compiler when building the code. So the annotation is only available in the source code, and not in the *.class* files, and not at runtime too.