# Annotation retention policy: what real benefit is there in declaring `SOURCE` or `CLASS`?

Tags: java, annotations

I know there are three retention policies for Java annotations:

> CLASS: Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.
>
> RUNTIME: Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively.
>
> SOURCE: Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

And although I understand their usage scenarios, I don't get why it is such an important thing to specify the retention policy that retention policies exist at all.

I mean, why aren't all the annotations just kept at runtime? Do they generate so much bytecode / occupy so much memory that stripping those not declared as `RUNTIME` does make that much difference?

Comment: I guess if you have a lot of annotations, they can take up to much space in a class file, so Java allows you to specify that a particular annotation isn't needed at run time, so it can be discarded.

Comment: `SOURCE` retention annotation can be used to disable warnings in IDEs like f.e `@SupressWarnings` while `CLASS` retention anntotation are useful if you deal with the byte-code (or byte-code manipulation framework like javassist) before the bytes are actually loaded into the VM via a classloader. The general intent is like in OOP to limit the scope of an annotation as much as possible - though in practice most annotations have retention `RUNTIME` as probably most programmers don`t care or want to use reflection to check if an annotation is available

Answer (score 2):

To actually answer the question: to reduce dependencies. If there would be no distinction between e.g. SOURCE and RUNTIME, the "user" of the classes would have to provide all the dependencies the annotations come from. So only because that annotation is used by the IDE (SOURCE), the jar would have to be provided during runtime - which is unnecessary. If you try to get annotations from a class, where no jar is provided that actually provides the annotation, you will get a class not found exception.

Comment: Wrong, unknown annotations are ignored by the JVM.
However, there was a bug in early versions of Java 5 that they weren't ignored: https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6322301

Answer (score 1):

Retention policy SOURCE is to aid IDEs, compilers and possibly code/doc generators to take advantage of annotations. These annotation do not make up part of compiled class and are discarded by compiler so not available during runtime.

For example, annotation `java.lang.SuppressWarnings` tells compiler not to report certain warnings.

Annotations to generate documentation can be of retention policy SOURCE.

Take a look at this post/answer [Annotation SOURCE Retention Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048941/annotation-source-retention-policy/8048965#8048965)

Comment: Yep, that's clear to me. What I didn't get is what would be so wrong to keep all retention at runtime that made the designers provide those policies. But I think I'm almost satisfied by the comments I got.

Comment: It would be unnecessary to include them at runtime, if its not design for runtime access and its going to be useless at that point of time. SOURCE annotation are processed directly on the source files (.java) and not class files. So, I dont see point to store them on the compiled class or load at runtime