# What is the use of RetentionPolicy.CLASS and RetentionPolicy.SOURCE?

Tags: java, annotations

What is the intended need for RetentionPolicy.CLASS and RetentionPolicy.SOURCE. In which annotation scenario, We can use these? I wanted some examples.

From the Java doc:

**CLASS: Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.**

- In which scenario, We will go for this as developer?

**SOURCE: Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.**

- In which scenario, We will go for this as developer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Annotation SOURCE Retention Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048941/annotation-source-retention-policy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do different retention policies affect my annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/how-do-different-retention-policies-affect-my-annotations)

Answer (score -1):

RetentionPolicy use to control the Lifetime and visibility of the annotations

**RetentionPolicy.CLASS** -  The defined annotation will be stored in the *.class* file, but not available at runtime. This is the default retention policy if you do not specify any retention policy at all.

**RetentionPolicy.SOURCE** - The defined annotation will be ignored by the compiler when building the code. So the annotation is only available in the source code, and not in the *.class* files, and not at runtime too.

Use two annotations depending on the use case with that *.class* files are not polluted unnecessarily.

If the annotation is used by build tools that scan the code, you can use **RetentionPolicy.SOURCE** retention policy.