# How will I know the annotations of a Java class?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I need to know the annotations of a Java class. I am using Lombok.

Sample is:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class JavaBean {}
```

I tried java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotation = JavaBean.class.getAnnotations but it doesn't show Data and Builder.

Comment: `@Data` generates all the boilerplate that is normally associated with simple POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) and beans: getters for all fields, setters for all non-final fields, and appropriate toString, equals and hashCode

Comment: for `@Builder` see https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Builder.html

Answer (score 4):

I think you cannot see the annotations in  JavaBean.class.getAnnotations  because the @Retention is equals to SOURCE.

This kind of annotation is not needed at runtime.

For more details : [Annotation SOURCE Retention Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048941/annotation-source-retention-policy)

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in source of these annotations:

```
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(SOURCE)
public @interface Builder {
.....

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Data {
.....
```

Your code to get annotation is correct but it's  `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` which is playing role here.

Java defined 3 types of retention policies through `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy` enumeration. It has `SOURCE`, `CLASS` and `RUNTIME`.

1) Annotation with retention policy `SOURCE` will be retained only with source code, and discarded during compile time.

2) Annotation with retention policy `CLASS` will be retained till compiling the code, and discarded during runtime.

3) Annotation with retention policy `RUNTIME` will be available to the JVM through runtime.

`@Data` and `@Builder` are marked with `@Retention(SOURCE)` which means these annotations are not present at runtime with your class hence you are not able to get these annotations..

Comment: And there is a good reason for this in the case of Lombok: you don't want every project you build with it to have runtime dependencies on Lombok jars.

Comment: @biziclop  also the purpose of these annotation gets completed just after compiling the code(Result in generated code which is expected by these Annotations) so there is no sense to retain the same at runtime.. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That is absolutely true too. I just thought someone might ask "Yes, but why can't we leave the annotations in anyway?". And the answer is that if they were retained till runtime, you couldn't load the classes without a JAR with the Lombok annotations on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Lombok annotations are pre-processed before the actual compilation, thus the compiled classes do not contain them as annotation, but rather as the already generated code.